# Function SQL Error Code : 1046

Tags: mysql, sql, function, error-code

This is my function query :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `dtkp`.`Tepat`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `dtkp`.`Tepat`(proses INT) RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE uid INTEGER;
    DECLARE total_hari_kerja INTEGER;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    SELECT total_hari_kerja = SUM (alokasi) FROM proses;

    DECLARE krk_uid CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT krk FROM krk_kartu_kendali WHERE proses <= 8 ;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempKK 
               (krk INT, terlambat INT) ENGINE=INNODB;

    OPEN krk_uid;
    tepatLoop:LOOP
        FETCH krk_uid INTO uid;
        IF done THEN
        LEAVE tepatLoop;
        END IF;

INSERT INTO tempKK 
SELECT krk, GetTepat(realisasi_tgl_terima, total_hari_kerja) terlambat 
      FROM krk_kartu_kendali 
      WHERE proses=1 
      and krk=uid 
      ORDER BY RecID 
      LIMIT 1;

    FETCH krk_uid INTO uid;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE krk_uid;
    DEALLOCATE krk_uid;
    RETURN ;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Error code : 1046
>
> > You have an error in your sql syntax : check the manual that corresponds  to your Mysql server version  for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Comment: your select statement is wrong it should be `SELECT SUM (alokasi) into total_hari_kerja   FROM proses;`

Comment: @Sachu Line 8 is " DECLARE krk_uid CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT krk FROM krk_kartu_kendali WHERE proses <= 8 ; " brother ,, Help me :)

Comment: did u try changing the select statement?

Comment: @Sachu done!! but error on " DECLARE krk_uid CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT krk FROM krk_kartu_kendali WHERE proses <= 8 ; "

Comment: whats the error saying?

Comment: @Sachu ( Error code : 1064 You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql Server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE krk_uid CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT krk FROM krk_kartu_kendali WHERE proses <= 8 ;' )

Comment: @Sachu done!! but what you mean " Also but a BEGIN ...END propery after all declaration "?? :)

Comment: sorry miscommunication did u try y answer below..any error now?

Comment: @Sachu Done!! i've tried, and error to use near 'END' at line 25

Comment: add a begin...end like in my answer below and check

Comment: @Sachu  I've tried brother but error like to use near 'END' at line 26..

Comment: @Hidayath your function should return an Int value..but u just wrote Return..where is the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself saying error is at line no:8
your line no: 8 is assigning a value to a variable from a table. The syntax is 
wrong

Also you are declaring a cursor and creating a temp table after the select statement. This is not the correct order..You should move the declare statement above..ie before starting any other statement..

Also your function should return an `INT` value but you only specified `Return;`..you should specify the value along with Return..i guesss it can be `total_hari_kerja`

try below

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `dtkp`.`Tepat`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `dtkp`.`Tepat`(proses INT) RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE uid INTEGER;
    DECLARE total_hari_kerja INTEGER;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE krk_uid CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT krk FROM krk_kartu_kendali WHERE
    proses <= 8 ;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempKK (krk INT, terlambat INT) ENGINE=INNODB;


   BEGIN
    SELECT SUM (alokasi) into total_hari_kerja FROM proses;



    OPEN krk_uid;
    tepatLoop:LOOP
        FETCH krk_uid INTO uid;
        IF done THEN
        LEAVE tepatLoop;
        END IF;

    INSERT INTO tempKK SELECT krk, GetTepat(realisasi_tgl_terima, total_hari_kerja) terlambat FROM krk_kartu_kendali WHERE proses=1 and krk=uid ORDER BY RecID LIMIT 1;
    FETCH krk_uid INTO uid;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE krk_uid;
    DEALLOCATE krk_uid;

    RETURN total_hari_kerja ;
     END$$
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```